# lpProgressRoutine callback in CopyFileEx fails to update the current and total bytes when trying to copy a file size more than 4.30 GB in VC++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

When trying to copy a file size more than 4.30 GB LPPROGRESS_ROUTINE lpProgressRoutine callback function is not updating the current bytes after **"4293918720"** bytes it is resetting to 0 and at the end of file copy it updates the current bytes as **"947912771"** which is wrong. actual file size is **"5242880067"** bytes. Once the copy is completed in system it shows correct file size.

Please tell me where can it go wrong.

code snippet

```
typedef struct CopyItemData {
        FileProgressCallback callback;
        void* data;
        uint64_t current;
        uint64_t total;
        Error result;
        BOOL cancel;
        int64_t tmpCurrent;
        int64_t tmpTotal;
    } CopyItemData;

int CopyFileInternal(const nstring& srcPath, const nstring& dstPath, FileProgressCallback callback, void* data){

CopyItemData cid;

        cid.callback = callback;
        cid.data = data;
        cid.current = 0;
        cid.total = 0;
        cid.result = SyncOK;
        cid.cancel = FALSE;

CopyFileEx((prefix + srcPath).c_str(), (prefix + dstPath).c_str(), CopyFileEx_progress, &cid, &cid.cancel, 0));
}

static DWORD WINAPI CopyFileEx_progress(
        LARGE_INTEGER TotalFileSize,
        LARGE_INTEGER TotalBytesTransferred,
        LARGE_INTEGER StreamSize,
        LARGE_INTEGER StreamBytesTransferred,
        DWORD dwStreamNumber,
        DWORD dwCallbackReason,
        HANDLE hSourceFile,
        HANDLE hDestinationFile,
        LPVOID lpData) {
        CopyItemData* pcid = reinterpret_cast<CopyItemData*>(lpData);
        
        if (pcid == nullptr)
            return PROGRESS_CANCEL;

        pcid->current = TotalBytesTransferred.QuadPart;
        pcid->total = TotalFileSize.QuadPart;

       pcid->result = pcid->callback(pcid->data, pcid->current, pcid->total);
       if (pcid->result != 0)
            return PROGRESS_CANCEL;

        return PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the type `LARGE_INTEGER` compared to `int64_t`